# leaflet map is not fully loaded when its in iron-page

Tags: javascript, polymer, leaflet, web-deployment

Backgroud:
I am using polymer framework to create a map service web app. And my map element is put inside iron-pages.

```
 <iron-pages attr-for-selected="id" selected="{{data.page}}">
           <main-page id="main"></main-page>
           <test-page id="page"></test-page>
      </iron-pages>
```

And the map element is inside the `<main-page id="main"></main-page>`

All the map settings are right , but the map is displaying like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOj5M.png)

Issue:
Just like the image above , the leaflet map is not fully loaded. However, when I resize the browser window, then the map loaded perfectly. It seems like the trigger to load the map became my resizing action?

My trials:

1. I tried to search others answer , https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/694

   But when I execute `map.invalidateSize()` , the console says   "`invalidateSize()` is not a function".
2. I tried to put   `<main-page id="main"></main-page>` out of `<iron-pages>` which forsake routing feature temporarily for testing, and the map works perfectly.But What is the real issue in this circumstance?

I am very new to polymer, I am not sure where is the issue come from?
Could you please give me any suggestion?

Thank you!